# Add an argument to application's JVM args

Tags: ubuntu, jvm, azure-application-insights

I would like to add an argument that points to a applicationinsights-agent-3.4.7.jar file
the argument being -javaagent:"path/to/applicationinsights-agent-3.4.7.jar. I'm trying to add that in a Build agent VM that runs Ubuntu in Azure DevOps. I'm doing this on an application that already has Java installed and but I can't find a command to find the JVM file or just the location of the file. Any help is appreciated.

I tried installing Tomcat and I thought I could change it from there but I'm automating all those steps and I can't seem to be able to do so.

Comment: THis all depends on how you run that java application. Typically, it's just modifying its startup script to `java -javaagent:"path/to/applicationinsights-agent-3.4.7.jar ...`

Comment: Is there a way I can find the startup script? Sorry I'm asking because I'm not the one who wrote the code for it I was just asked to do that since the person who did is not here anymore